Unable to Download PHP Files in DirectAdmin CustomBuild
I am encountering an issue with DirectAdmin's CustomBuild tool. When I attempt to build PHP using the built-in functionality in DirectAdmin's control panel, I receive the following error message:

curl: (22) The requested URL returned error: 404 Not Found Download of https://files.directadmin.com/services/custombuild/php-8.1.16.tar.gz failed, re-downloading the file... Download of https://files.directadmin.com/services/custombuild/php-8.1.16.tar.gz failed 4 times, exiting...

It appears that the PHP files necessary for the build process are not available at the specified URL (https://files.directadmin.com/services/custombuild). As a result, I am unable to proceed with building PHP.
I have attempted the build process multiple times, but the issue persists. Is anyone else experiencing similar difficulties, or does anyone have insight into why the PHP files may not be available?
Any assistance or guidance on resolving this issue would be greatly appreciated.
=====================
update : Missing PHP Versions in DirectAdmin CustomBuild Directory
Upon investigating the directory (https://files.directadmin.com/services/custombuild/), I noticed that there are no PHP versions available.

I fixed it by making slight adjustments in the CustomBuild build file. Here is what I did:
You have to go to /usr/local/directadmin/custombuild and open the build file.
Look for this line:
declare "PHP${php_shortrelease}_DOWNLOADURL=${WEBPATH}/php-${PHP_VERSION_NUMBER}.tar.gz"

Replace it with this one:
declare "PHP${php_shortrelease}_DOWNLOADURL=https://www.php.net/distributions/php-${PHP_VERSION_NUMBER}.tar.gz"


While this method works, be aware that updates to DirectAdmin might overwrite your changes. In my case, DirectAdmin updates are disabled.

This can happen if your version of DirectAdmin is old. Try updating DirectAdmin and then try updating your php. This may solve your problem.
